# RunntimeException for doinbackground in Asynchronous Task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am developing an application to view Call history using Asynchronous task. When i run my application in Jeally Bean(4.2.2) it works fine but in Kitkat(4.4.1) it shows an error as below.
Please help me how to solve this error. Thanks in advance

> 12-11 18:34:57.892: E/AndroidRuntime(4744): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask
>
> ## 1 12-11 18:34:57.892: E/AndroidRuntime(4744): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>
> doInBackground() 12-11 18:34:57.892: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):  at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299) 12-11 18:34:57.892:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4744):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
>   12-11 18:34:57.892: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
>   12-11 18:34:57.892: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239) 12-11
>   18:34:57.892: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 12-11
>   18:34:57.892: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>   12-11 18:34:57.892: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>   12-11 18:34:57.892: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838) 12-11 18:34:57.892:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4744): Caused by:
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
>   12-11 18:34:57.892: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:5288) 12-11
>   18:34:57.892: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.focusableViewAvailable(ViewRootImpl.java:2919)
>   12-11 18:34:57.892: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:613)
>   12-11 18:34:57.892: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:613)
>   12-11 18:34:57.892: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:613)
>   12-11 18:34:57.892: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:613)
>   12-11 18:34:57.892: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:613)
>   12-11 18:34:57.892: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:613)
>   12-11 18:34:57.892: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:613)
>   12-11 18:34:57.892: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):   at
>   android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:8463) 12-11 18:34:57.892:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4744):   at
>   android.view.View.setFocusableInTouchMode(View.java:5802) 12-11
>   18:34:57.892: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):     at
>   android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:717) 12-11
>   18:34:57.892: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):     at
>   android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:467) 12-11
>   18:34:57.892: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):     at
>   com.example.testphonegap.DialledCallsFrag.GetList(DialledCallsFrag.java:42)
>   12-11 18:34:57.892: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):   at
>   com.example.testphonegap.DialledCallsFrag.setDialledCalls(DialledCallsFrag.java:35)
>   12-11 18:34:57.892: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):   at
>   com.example.testphonegap.CallHistoryValues$GetCallLogs.doInBackground(CallHistoryValues.java:118)
>   12-11 18:34:57.892: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):   at
>   com.example.testphonegap.CallHistoryValues$GetCallLogs.doInBackground(CallHistoryValues.java:1)
>   12-11 18:34:57.892: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):   at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287) 12-11 18:34:57.892:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4744):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234) 12-11
>   18:34:57.892: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):     ... 4 more

Comment: Thanks!.... for who have given there precocious time for my question and given valuable answer.. Now i solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views*** means you are performing some UI related operations in doInBackground() method you cant do that because doInBackground() id runs on Separate non-UI thread. Android doesn't allow you to perform UI operations there.

Answer (score 0):

The below line is crucial:

```
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Are you doing anything in the AsyncTask that affects a View object in the Activity or Fragment? Is so, do it only in `onProgress()` and `onPostExecute()`, as those two methods are invoked on the UI Thread.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing a View from the AsyncTask method doInBackground(...). This method always runs on a new thread, separate from the calling thread.

If you're starting the AsyncTask inside an Activity, you can call the View as follows:

```
MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {
                //access view here
            }
        });
```

But the best solution is to access the View in AsyncTask's onPostExecute(), which will be called after doInBackground() and which runs on the calling thread.